# What is the formula for this function $f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) \cdots (x-k)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I wonder if there exists a formula for this function?
$$f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) \cdots (x-k)$$
I want to know the coefficient of each $x^i$, and the first thing I came up with was to find the expansion of this expression. Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm guessing that the $k$ in the formula for $f$ is not the same as the $k$ in "I want to know the coefficient of each $x^k$", so I suggest you change the latter to *"of each $x^i$"* to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: You're just so right ^_^! Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look up the [Stirling numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number) and the falling factorial.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use Pochhammer symbols to represent these entities.